# Readable html after Pug

Tags: html, pug, readability

I know I can pass the `pretty:true` option to Pug but unfortunately I get the white space html bug for inline-block elements whose total width should add up to 100%; So `pretty:true` is only causing trouble in my case (+ it will be deprecated). But I would like to have a readable html output. Checking up the code in the browser every time is not so convenient. **gulp-pug-beautify** is something I tried so far but the output is still a mess. Is there any other plugin/package that can do the job ?

Answer (score 0):

You can resort to CSS fixes to get rid of the white space HTML bug. And it is a much standard way as well.

You need to set the `font-size` of parent element (or a wrapper element) to `0` and then set the font-size of the child to a desired value or `initial`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Alternate answer

In case you can't modify the css, you can always use the HTML syntax in Pug.

Example

```
ul <li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li>
```

will output to,

```
<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li></ul>
```